# How to disable Low Disk Space red bar in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

I would like to make these "Red drives" look same as those blue ones.
Nothing serious, just annoying when watching it.

[image: A piclip...]

Comment: I doubt if there is an option to change the percentage for the low space warnings on the computer, you either have to delete unnecessary content in respective drives or remove the color bars altogether through registry

Comment: @xavier_fakerat is there a way to switch the red color to blue(same as default)?

Comment: Is there a way to change only the color?